# Navigation ExpansionTile when tap flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building a flutter app and I'm using the example code for `ExpansionTile`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpansionTileSample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile'),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              new EntryItem(data[index]),
          itemCount: data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// One entry in the multilevel list displayed by this app.
class Entry {
  Entry(this.title, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);

  final String title;
  final List<Entry> children;
}

// The entire multilevel list displayed by this app.
final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
  new Entry(
    'Chapter A',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry(
        'Section A0',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Item A0.1'),
          new Entry('Item A0.2'),
          new Entry('Item A0.3'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Section A1'),
      new Entry('Section A2'),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry(
    'Chapter B',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Section B0'),
      new Entry('Section B1'),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry(
    'Chapter C',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Section C0'),
      new Entry('Section C1'),
      new Entry(
        'Section C2',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Item C2.0'),
          new Entry('Item C2.1'),
          new Entry('Item C2.2'),
          new Entry('Item C2.3'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
];

// Displays one Entry. If the entry has children then it's displayed
// with an ExpansionTile.
class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);

  final Entry entry;

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) return new ListTile(
       onTap: () { print("I can be tapped but I dont't figure out how to navigate"); },
       title: new Text(root.title));
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample/

I want to tap on the lower items (Item A0.1, Item A0.2, Item A0.3, Item C2.0 and so on) to navigate through other page (one different each time). I added  `onTap` but I only could print something into the console . How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the context from `ListView.builder` to `EntryItem` method when creating it and use it in `OnClick` to navigate to `OtherPage`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new ExpansionTileSample());

class ExpansionTileSample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile'),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
          new EntryItem(data[index], context),
          itemCount: data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// One entry in the multilevel list displayed by this app.
class Entry {
  Entry(this.title, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);

  final String title;
  final List<Entry> children;
}

// The entire multilevel list displayed by this app.
final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
  new Entry(
    'Chapter A',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry(
        'Section A0',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Item A0.1'),
          new Entry('Item A0.2'),
          new Entry('Item A0.3'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Section A1'),
      new Entry('Section A2'),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry(
    'Chapter B',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Section B0'),
      new Entry('Section B1'),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry(
    'Chapter C',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Section C0'),
      new Entry('Section C1'),
      new Entry(
        'Section C2',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Item C2.0'),
          new Entry('Item C2.1'),
          new Entry('Item C2.2'),
          new Entry('Item C2.3'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
];

// Displays one Entry. If the entry has children then it's displayed
// with an ExpansionTile.
class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry, this.context);

  final Entry entry;
  final BuildContext context;

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) return new ListTile(
        onTap: () { print("I can be tapped but I dont't figure out how to navigate");
        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return new OtherScreen();
        }));
        },
        title: new Text(root.title));
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there any way to specify which item I am tapping to go to other page each time? I used to do this in java with some conditional statements but I'm having some issues in flutter

Comment: Yeah. `_buildTiles` method contains the reference of each inner list item in `root` variable. You can pass this `root.title` to the Other page inside `_buildTiles` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to screen by pushing MaterialPageRoute to Navigator

`print('Navigate to SomePageClass');
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SomePageClass()));`

Comment: Its what I want but I don´t know how to get the context. How could I set the context, for example, for `Item A0.1`?

Comment: take a look at ```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }``

you can pass the BuildContext to _buildTiles function

Comment: I tried it but I'm getting other error. I neither know how to select each item to go for its specific route. That would send me always to the same route. Could you give a reproducible example?